# .Net TrackMouseEvent not working with Sub Menu Items

Tags: vb.net, winapi, custom-controls, contextmenu

I am adding some functionality to a custom ContextMenuStrip control that I have created.

One of the first things that I need to do is increase the mouse hover time on the submenu context items.  The following code works perfectly for the main context items, but will not fire my mouse hover event for submenu items.

I believe the problem is that I need to set the tme.hWnd handle to the submenu.  If that is the case, how do I get the handle of the submenu as it is opening?

Thanks!

```
    Friend Const WM_MOUSEMOVE As Integer = &H200
    Friend Const WM_MOUSELEAVE As Integer = &H2A3
    Friend Const TME_LEAVE As Integer = &H2

    Private _mouseOver As Boolean = False
    Private _mouseOverHandel As IntPtr = Me.Handle

    Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)

        Select Case m.Msg
            Case WM_MOUSEMOVE
                If Not _mouseOver Then

                    Dim tme As New TRACKMOUSEEVENTR()
                    tme.hWnd = _mouseOverHandel
                    tme.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(GetType(TRACKMOUSEEVENTR))
                    tme.dwFlags = TMEFlags.TME_HOVER
                    tme.dwHoverTime = 1000 * 3
                    TrackMouseEvent(tme)

                    _mouseOver = True
                End If

                MyBase.WndProc(m)
                Exit Select

            Case WM_MOUSELEAVE
                _mouseOver = False
                MyBase.WndProc(m)
                Exit Select

            Case Else
                MyBase.WndProc(m)
        End Select

    End Sub


    <DllImport("user32.dll")> _
    Private Shared Function TrackMouseEvent(ByRef lpEventTrack As TRACKMOUSEEVENTR) As Integer
    End Function

    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
    Public Structure TRACKMOUSEEVENTR
        Public cbSize As Int32
        ' using Int32 instead of UInt32 is safe here, and this avoids casting the result  of Marshal.SizeOf()
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)> _
        Public dwFlags As TMEFlags
        Public hWnd As IntPtr
        Public dwHoverTime As UInt32

        Public Sub New(dwFlags As Int32, hWnd As IntPtr, dwHoverTime As UInt32)
            Me.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(GetType(TRACKMOUSEEVENTR))
            Me.dwFlags = dwFlags
            Me.hWnd = hWnd
            Me.dwHoverTime = dwHoverTime
        End Sub
    End Structure

    ''' <summary>
    ''' The services requested. This member can be a combination of the following values. 
    ''' </summary>
    <Flags()> _
    Public Enum TMEFlags As UInteger
        TME_CANCEL = &H80000000UI
        TME_HOVER = &H1
        TME_LEAVE = &H2
        TME_NONCLIENT = &H10
        TME_QUERY = &H40000000
    End Enum
```

Comment: Sub-menu items don't have a handle.  No easy fix for this, the mouse handling for them is locked up inside Winforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to go another way to solve this. I'll leave this here for anyone that needs it.

I created a MouseMove and MouseLeave handler for my dynamic submenu items.

Inside the MouseMove

```
If Not _mouseSubOver Then

    _tsmi = sender

    _itemDelayTimer = New Timer()
    _itemDelayTimer.Interval = Math.Max(1, 1500)
    AddHandler _itemDelayTimer.Tick, AddressOf OnDelayTimerExpire
    _itemDelayTimer.Start()

    _mouseSubOver = True

End If
```

Inside MouseLeave

```
If _itemDelayTimer IsNot Nothing Then
    _itemDelayTimer.Stop()
    _itemDelayTimer.Dispose()
    _itemDelayTimer = Nothing
End If

_mouseSubOver = False
```

Inside OnDelayTimerExpire

```
 Private Sub OnDelayTimerExpire(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        If _itemDelayTimer IsNot Nothing Then

            _itemDelayTimer.Stop()
            _itemDelayTimer.Dispose()
            _itemDelayTimer = Nothing

        End If

        'Do your sub menu stuff here
 End Sub
```